# Actions in onActivityResult and "Error Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Implementing an app where the user can log in I have the following situation: If the user is logged in perform the action else start the login activity for result and if the result is Activity.RESULT_OK do the action.

My problem is that the action to perfom is to show a DialogFragment, but calling

```
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
newFragment.show(ft, "dialog")
```

in the onActivityResult callback throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

So how can I solve this? I'm thinking in raising a flag there and show the dialog in the onResume but I see this solution a little dirty

Edit: Added more code (Im following this example for showing the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

When the action is requested by the user:

```
... 
if (!user.isLogged()){
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(cnt, Login.class), REQUEST_LOGIN_FOR_COMMENT);
}
```

In the same fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOGIN_FOR_COMMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(ft, "dialog")
    }
}
```

And if the user logs in the Login activity calls;

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Comment: i think you should post the whole code. Seems like you are trying to show dialog after onpause

Comment: Check http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html to understand why this is happening

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Best thing I've come up with is to not use .show() but rather do this.

```
CheckinSuccessDialog dialog = new CheckinSuccessDialog();
//dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(dialog, null);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Although it works for me, I feel unsafe cause we left out 2 variables : mDismissed = false; mShownByMe = true; The above variables are being modified in original show function.

Comment: mDismissed and mShowByMe seem to be variables specifically to track if the dialog was shown/hidden by outside calls. In other words they compensate for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: How you can "remove" the dialog

Comment: have you tried to call super.onActivityResult() at the first line of  activityOnResult?

Comment: yeah uhm but..... WHY?! what is Android doing wrong here (or is it)? Why do we need this workaround? schwiz do you know the reason?

Comment: Calling `super.onActivityResult()` fixed it for me, try this before doing the workaround.

Comment: @Sakiboy awesome, you should put that as a separate answer! Do you have any idea why it works and if it's safe?

Comment: `super.onActivityResult()` allows Android to do its inner state change and state loss is no longer possible. This is why it works. That should be the proper answer.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the workaround that works fine for me.

```
private void alert(final String message) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(message);
            alertDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), ALERT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: can you explain the magic?

Answer (score 4):

If using a DialogFragment, the only thing that worked for me was to dismiss the Fragment with dissmissAllowingStateLoss()

Answer (score 4):

I simply check whether an activity is being destroyed.

```
if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
    DialogFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), MyFragment.TAG);
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813953/2914140. In `DialogFragment` write:

```
override fun show(manager: FragmentManager?, tag: String?) {
    try {
        val ft = manager?.beginTransaction()
        ft?.add(this, tag)
        ft?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `show(Fragment manager, String tag)` function with allowing state lose and change `mDismissed = false;` `mShownByMe = true;` from origibal function by reflection:

```
public class DialogParent extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        try {
            Field mDismissed = DialogFragment.class.getDeclaredField("mDismissed");
            Field mShownByMe = DialogFragment.class.getDeclaredField("mShownByMe");
            mDismissed.setAccessible(true);
            mShownByMe.setAccessible(true);
            mDismissed.setBoolean(this, false);
            mShownByMe.setBoolean(this, true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could likewise surround the parents show method with a try-catch, where you in the catch add the dialog and use your transaction calling `commitAllowingStateLoss()`. This way you don't need any reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `super.onActivityResult()` before showing the dialog

Answer (score 0):

This real works.

```
CheckinSuccessDialog dialog = new CheckinSuccessDialog();
//dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(dialog, null);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But but still bad, because got error “Activity has been destroyed”

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

So my solution is add check `if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed())`

```
CheckinSuccessDialog fragment = CheckinSuccessDialog.newInstance();

     if (fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
                DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fragment;
                if (!dialog.isAdded()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.add(dialog, 
                          CheckinSuccessDialog.class.getName());
                    if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }
```

on dismiss:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CheckinSuccessDialog.class.getName());
        if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
            DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fragment;
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed()) {
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown whenever a `FragmentTrasaction` is commited after `FragmentManager` has saved its state. The easy and clean way is to check if `FragmentManager` has already saved state before showing a `DialogFragment`.

```
if(!getSupportFragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment()
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager, TAG);
}
```