# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on DialogFragment

Tags: android, progressdialog

There are several questions on StackOverflow, but non of them incorporating DialogFragment. The usual solution is to use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`. But how do I accomplish that for `DialogFragment`?

The following is the code of `show()` method of `DialogFragment`. There's `ft.commit()` on it but I cannot change it to `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Here how I implement `DialogFragment`

```
public class ProgressFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private String message;

    public static ProgressFragment getInstance() {
        return new ProgressFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);

        return progressDialog;
    }

    public void show(String message, FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        this.message = message;
        show(manager, tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, [you can change it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

See [On showing dialog i get "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729138/on-showing-dialog-i-get-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate):

```
public class ProgressFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        try {
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(this, tag);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
}
```